# Keeping track of the tennis score

Tags: c++, interview-questions

I'm trying to get hired by some company and they gave me a simple remote test to take at home so they can judge my coding skills.

It's a really simple problem based on the website HackerRank. It's a mini game where you have to keep track of the score of a tennis game (0-15-30-40-ADV).

This is really basic and I managed to do it without any problems. But I believe the more important thing is not if it works or not but rather how you did it and if you did code like a professional.

What could I improve on in [my code](https://gist.github.com/NephChevsky/3521141bdb7e4df22165daf44ba3645e) to actually code like a professional?

```
//======================================
// Author: Philippe Balleydier
// Last Update : 08/09/16
// Object : Little algorithm able to keep track of the tennis score
//======================================


#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// score map for printing the score
const string Score[] = {"0", "15", "30", "40", "ADV"};

//======================================
// Class Game: contains all the informations and methods about the game being played
//======================================
class Game
{
    // see below for explanations
    public:
    Game();
    bool createPlayer(int playerId, string playerName);
    string getName(int playerId);
    bool hasADV(int playerId);
    bool setScore(int playerId, int score);
    int getIntScore(int playerId);
    string getStringScore(int playerId);

    private:
    string players[2]; // players' name
    int scores[2]; // players' score
};


//--------------------------------------
// Constructor : init score to 0
//--------------------------------------
Game::Game()
{
    scores[0] = 0;
    scores[1] = 0;
}

//--------------------------------------
// createPlayer : create a player depending on its ID
//--------------------------------------
bool Game::createPlayer(int playerId, string playerName)
{
    if (playerId == 0 || playerId == 1)
    {
        players[playerId] = playerName;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

//--------------------------------------
// getName : return the name of player "playerId" as a string
//--------------------------------------
string Game::getName(int playerId)
{
    if (playerId == 0 || playerId == 1)
        return players[playerId];
    else
        return "N/A";
}

//--------------------------------------
// getName : return true if the player's score is ADV, else false
//--------------------------------------
bool Game::hasADV(int playerId)
{
    if (scores[playerId]==4)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//--------------------------------------
// setScore : change the score of player "playerId"
//--------------------------------------
bool Game::setScore(int playerId, int score)
{
    if (score < 5)
        scores[playerId]=score;
    else
        return false;
}

//--------------------------------------
// getIntScore : return the score of player "playerId" as a int (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
//--------------------------------------
int Game::getIntScore(int playerId)
{
    return scores[playerId];
}

//--------------------------------------
// getStringScore : return the score of player "playerId" as a string (0, 15, 30, 40, ADV)
//--------------------------------------
string Game::getStringScore(int playerId)
{
    return Score[scores[playerId]];
}
//=======================================

int main()
{
    // rand init
    srand(time(NULL));

    // setting up the game
    Game myGame;
    myGame.createPlayer(0, "John");
    myGame.createPlayer(1, "Paul");

    //starting game loop
    bool stop = false;
    while(!stop)
    {
        // identifying winner and looser
        int pointWinner = rand()%2;
        int pointLooser=(pointWinner+1)%2;
        cout << "The winner of the point is " << myGame.getName(pointWinner) << endl;

        // The pointWinner has advantage => win
        if (myGame.hasADV(pointWinner))
        {
            stop = true;
            cout << "Winner is " << myGame.getName(pointWinner) << endl;
        } // The opponent has advantage => tie (40-40)
        else if (myGame.hasADV(pointLooser))
            myGame.setScore(pointLooser, 3);
        // Tie (40-40) => pointWinner gets advantage
        else if (myGame.getIntScore(pointWinner)==3 && myGame.getIntScore(pointLooser) == 3)
            myGame.setScore(pointWinner, 4);
        //pointWinner is 1 point ahead of pointLooser and >=30
        else if (myGame.getIntScore(pointWinner)>myGame.getIntScore(pointLooser) && myGame.getIntScore(pointWinner)>=2)
        {
            stop = true;
            cout << "Winner is " << myGame.getName(pointWinner) << endl;
        }
        else // nothing special, pointWinner marks the point
            myGame.setScore(pointWinner, myGame.getIntScore(pointWinner)+1);

        // printing score
        if (!stop)
            cout << "Score : " << myGame.getName(0) << " " << myGame.getStringScore(0) << " - " << myGame.getStringScore(1) << " " << myGame.getName(1) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Just so you know, it has to be a 1-page .cpp file, so I can't really split the `Game` class into different .h and .cpp files.

Comment: While I have a thing or two to say about the dishonesty in turning in interview code that has been significantly improved by experienced programmers, someone could rightfully refute by saying that you could have just omitted that this was part of an interview process and thus none of us would have been the wiser (including your potential employer). Therefore, I'll leave you with this- don't turn in work that isn't yours. I'm not saying you can't use Google, but if your company sees the level of code you turn in from here,

Comment: that's what they're going to be expecting if they hire you. Except they aren't going to give you the time to write your code, post it here, and wait for an answer. Additionally, users here may not always be apt to give improved solutions to actual boring _work-related_ code; this case, you're code was fun "game" code. Then what will you do when your bosses see code that is a few years less mature than what you turned in from your interview? Mention, "Oh that code I turned it? I got direct assistance from an online community first." I mean, @Loki made some _great_ improvements... so be wise.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### Overall

You missed the point.
If you are supposed to create a class to track the score of game you did it wrong. Most of the logic that should be inside the class has been left inside main.

If you see the pattern:

1. Get info from object.
2. Manipulate data.
3. Update state of object.

This usually means that you should have a function called `Manipulate()` (where Manipulate is the action you are doing).

I would expect the logic running the game to be:

```
while(game)
{
     game.winPoint(rand() % 2);
     std::cout << game << "\n";
}
std::cout << "Winner was: " << game.winner() << "\n";
```

Thus your interface to the class should be:

```
class Game
{
    public:
        // returns true if the game is still being played
        bool operator() const;

        // A player won a point (updates the state.
        void winPoint(int playerId);

        // return a reference to the winning player.
        // If the game is not finished calling this is UB.
        Player& winner() const;

        // Print the current state of the game.
        void print(std::ostream& str) const;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Game const& g)
        {
            g.print(s);
            return s;
        }
};
```

### Code Review

#### Comments.

Comments should be meaningful.

A bad comment is worse than no comment. This is because like code, comments need to be maintained. If the comments and code fall out of sync then what does a maintainer do? Fix the code or fix the comment?

So comments should be for describing why (not how).

The first two lines are OK.

```
//======================================
// Author: Philippe Balleydier
// Last Update : 08/09/16
// Object : Little algorithm able to keep track of the tennis score
//======================================
```

The trouble is the third line is not accurate. It's not an algorithm it's a class.

This comment on the other hand is completely useless. It tells me nothing that I don't already know.

```
//======================================
// Class Game: contains all the informations and methods about the game being played
//======================================
```

#### Header files.

These are C header files.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
```

There are C++ versions of these header files. The C++ versions put all the appropriate declarations in the namespace `std`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

#### Never Do this.

```
using namespace std;
```

If you had read any other C++ review on this board it would have told you not to do this. See: [Why is “using namespace std” in C++ considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/14065).

There is a reason that the standard libraries are called `std` and not `standard`. Its to make prefixing them easy.

#### This should be a private member of the class.

```
// score map for printing the score
const string Score[] = {"0", "15", "30", "40", "ADV"};
```

#### Better indenting

Nice indenting is critical to coding. The compiler does not care. But the code will have to be read by humans long after you abandon this code to some poor maintainer. So please make it easy to read.

```
    class Game
    {
        // see below for explanations
        public:
   =>   Game();
   =>   bool createPlayer(int playerId, string playerName);
```

I want to see that those methods are inside the public region of the class.

### Constructor

Is that comment telling me something I can not read in the code. Remove useless comment.

```
//--------------------------------------
// Constructor : init score to 0
//--------------------------------------
Game::Game()
{
    scores[0] = 0;
    scores[1] = 0;
}
```

The problem is that you have not set up the class completely. You have just created an empty object. You require the user of your class to make two further calls to set up the players before the class is ready to use. This means I can accidentally start using the class before it is completely set up.

I would have done it like this:

```
 Player player1("Loki");
 Player player2("Thor");
 Game   game(player1, player2);

 // Game is now in a valid state and ready to go.
```

### Use exceptions when you have an error

```
bool Game::createPlayer(int playerId, string playerName)
```

OK so I fail to add a player now what. The fact that you have an error condition probably means that there is a serious flaw in your code (the code that is calling the class) so your application should probably fail fast rather than try to continue.

```
if (!myGame.createPlayer(2, "Bob"))
{
    // Failed to create player.
    // what can I do here?
}
```

Also you return an error code but fail to even try and check it in your main application. That is a serious flaw (especially in interview code).

```
myGame.createPlayer(0, "John");  // returns an unchecked bool !!!!!
myGame.createPlayer(1, "Paul");
```

#### Getter/Setter Bad practice

It means you are leaking implementation details of the code. Prefer to use action methods that internally mutate the state of the object.

Note: Getter/Setter are fine on object bags; but not on classes.

Aside: Another bad comment (on each function). The comment is unneeded because the function is well named, so well that I can see exactly what it is doing without the comment.

```
//--------------------------------------
// getName : return the name of player "playerId" as a string
//--------------------------------------
string Game::getName(int playerId)    
bool Game::hasADV(int playerId)
bool Game::setScore(int playerId, int score)    
int Game::getIntScore(int playerId)
string Game::getStringScore(int playerId)
```

#### Use the new random number

```
    // rand init
    srand(time(NULL));
```

Sure it works. For this kind of example it is also fine. But this is an interview question. You want to show that you are up-to-date with modern C++ so use the new random number stuff.

#### Main

`main()` is special. If you don't return a value from main then the compiler will plant `return 0;` for you. So don't add a return to main.

I use the fact that if there is a `return 0;` in my code that it indicates that at another point in main there is a return that is not zero.

Comment: "Getter/Setter are fine on object bags", is that true? In that case surely you just want a struct with direct access to the objects inside?

Comment: @cloakedlearning: Yes I prefer just making them open structs. But sometimes you want getters/setters (but I could be argued out of that position very easily). You just want to avoid them on classes.

Comment: I agree the comment prior to the definition of `Game::Game()` should be deleted; in fact in my experience it very rarely makes sense to write a comment above a function definition. But it can be good to write a comment above the function _declaration_ that says what the function does. In larger projects this is especially valuable if you make the comment suitable for a documentation generator--even if what the comment says would be obvious from looking at the function definition.

Comment: @DavidK  Document generate will put the function definition as well. If there is no comment but the code is self documenting it comes to the same effect. Anything complex though should have a comment (and a comment that describes "what" (just not "how")).

Comment: The point of the document generator is mainly what it gives you that is _not_ a copy of the compilation unit containing the function definition. I'm not recommending "sets some_internal_variable to 0" as a good comment, but the main reason it's hard to write a good comment for `Game::Game()` is that _what_ it does (set the players' scores to the start of the game without saying who is playing) doesn't make much sense. Define the function according to your recommendation instead, and then "Starts a game between player1 and player2" might be a useful comment.

Comment: @MartinYork Very good inputs, especially on the usage of comments (some of which I overlooked prior). One small question. In this `Game` class where you said "This comment on the other hand is completely useless. It tells me nothing that I don't already know." what comment would you put there instead? What else was he supposed to say here? Nothing is preferable? Should we just not add comments when something is obvious? Comments express intent so you can immediately reason about the code. (finally adding `return 0;` in main isn't bad practice at all.)

Comment: @Nik-Lz: Comments: Use comments to explain **WHAT** you are trying to achieve. Use **Self Document** code to explain **HOW** you are doing it. Comments that explain the code are useless (worse than useless I would consider then harmful). This is because comments that explain code need to be maintained with the code.Unfortunately this rarely happens and the code and comments fall out of sync. So now a maintainer has to either fix the comment or fix the code but which! Self documenting code should make the need for comments that explain the code redundant (so no comments on how the code works).

Comment: @Nik-Lz: Return in main: I would not argue its bad practice. I would argue that a more common style (unlike C) is not to use `return 0` **when that is the only way** to exit the application. It is an indicator that there is only one exit code possible. Use `return 0` to indicate to the maintainer that there are other exit codes and `main()` should be read carefully. Use no return to indicate that this is a simple application that as far as the OS is concerned always works.

Answer (score 17):

@Loki Astari is completely right in his points. Apart from that you should consolidate your logic, as currently you have 5 clauses for 3 cases, which are:

1. `pointWinner` wins the game
2. `pointLoser` had advantage
3. Everything else

So you have overcomplicated the code, which is also true for those setters and getters.

---

Think about what is necessary and what are the correct types. Your score is an int. Is there any meaning of an negative score? If no use unsigned.

---

You should put things together that belong together. A player has a name and a score and a game has two payers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
class Game {
    using player = std::pair<std::string, unsigned>;
private:
    std::vector<player> players;
}
```

Now how do we get a game? We need two players identified by their names which start both at 0. Note that we do not allow any other constructor via explicit keyword and seed the RNG.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
class Game {
    using player = std::pair<std::string, unsigned>;
public:
    explicit Game(const std::string &name1, const std::string &name2)
    : players({player(name1, 0), player(name2, 0)}) {srand(time(NULL));}
private:
    std::vector<player> players;
}
```

Next think about what is happening during the game. The players are playing a point, the game and we are telling the score, which gives us the following public functions:

```
void playGame (void)
void playPoint (void)
void printScore (void)
```

So let's implement the functions (for simplicity I do not use a .cpp file which you should most likely).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
class Game {
    using player = std::pair<std::string, unsigned>;
public:
    explicit Game(const std::string &name1, const std::string &name2)
    : players({player(name1, 0), player(name2, 0)}) {srand(time(NULL));}

    void printScore (unsigned pointWinner) {
        if (gameWon == -1) {
        std::cout << players.at(pointWinner).first << " made a point. "
                  << "The current score is: \n";
        std::cout << players.at(0).first << ":\t"
                  << Scores.at(players.at(0).second) << std::endl;
        std::cout << players.at(1).first << ":\t"
                  << Scores.at(players.at(1).second) << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << players.at(pointWinner).first << " won the game.\n";
        }
    }

    void playGame (void) {
        while (gameWon == -1) {
            playPoint();
        }
    }

    void playPoint (void) {
        unsigned pointWinner = rand()%2;
        unsigned pointLoser  = (pointWinner+1)%2;

        if (players.at(pointWinner).second == 4 ||
            (players.at(pointWinner).second == 3 &&
             players.at(pointLoser).second < 3)) {
            gameWon = pointWinner;
        } else if (players.at(pointLoser).second == 4) {
            players.at(pointLoser).second--;
        } else {
            players.at(pointWinner).second++;
        }
            printScore(pointWinner);
    }

private:
    std::vector<player> players;
    int gameWon = -1;
    const std::vector<std::string> Scores = {"0", "15", "30", "45", "Adv"};
};
```

---

So we play a point. Flip a coin and check if the game is won. We print the score depending whether the game has ended or not. We play the game as long as it is not ended. Now we have to think about what we need to make publicly 
available.

`printScore` is only used in `playPoint`, which in turn is only used in `playGame`, so these two can be `private` functions.

```
class Game {
    using player = std::pair<std::string, unsigned>;
public:
    explicit Game(const std::string &name1, const std::string &name2)
    : players({player(name1, 0), player(name2, 0)}) {srand(time(NULL));}

    void playGame (void) {
        while (gameWon == -1) {
            playPoint();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<player> players;
    int gameWon = -1;
    const std::vector<std::string> Scores = {"0", "15", "30", "45", "Adv"};

    void playPoint (void) {
        unsigned pointWinner = rand()%2;
        unsigned pointLoser  = (pointWinner+1)%2;

        if (players.at(pointWinner).second == 4 ||
            (players.at(pointWinner).second == 3 &&
             players.at(pointLoser).second < 3)) {
            gameWon = pointWinner;
        } else if (players.at(pointLoser).second == 4) {
            players.at(pointLoser).second--;
        } else {
            players.at(pointWinner).second++;
        }
            printScore(pointWinner);
    }

    void printScore (unsigned pointWinner) {
        if (gameWon == -1) {
        std::cout << players.at(pointWinner).first << " made a point. "
                  << "The current score is: \n";
        std::cout << players.at(0).first << ":\t"
                  << Scores.at(players.at(0).second) << std::endl;
        std::cout << players.at(1).first << ":\t"
                  << Scores.at(players.at(1).second) << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << players.at(pointWinner).first << " won the game.\n";
        }
    }
};
```

And your `main` is simply:

```
#include "Tennis.h"
int main()
{
    Game USOpen= Game("Loki", "Thor");
    USOpen.playGame();
}
```

Comment: I disagree with `If no use unsigned`. The only time to really use unsigned is when using an integer as a set of bit flags. The trouble is that passing an unsigned to a signed interface is that it will be auto converted to an unsigned value; after which is undetectable (apart from it is probably big). Its easier to use a signed value which allows you to check for negative values.

Comment: I found a bug in my code, gameWon is checked against 0 which is the first player. It should have been int gameWon = -1 and checked against that or unsigned gameWon and checked against <2

Comment: @LokiAstari I wouldnt say that in general, for example for loops it is generally better to use unsigned/size_t. However, the comment was more about use the correct type depending on the problem.

Comment: Why not use an enum? The score isn't really a number, it's one of a small number of values.

Comment: Yeah an enum would in principle improve readability. Actually the best thing would be a map<enum, std::string> so that we can use this for printing too

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
```

Organize your header files.  Larger programs will have a longer list of includes.  Maintainers of your code will want to be able to trace your list of includes efficiently, and there is no faster way than binary search on a sorted list.

Prefer the C++ Standard Library headers.  Use of the C Standard Library headers is deprecated by the standard and should be avoided with new codebases.

*Note—* Any reference to the C++ Standard document refers to the last public draft of the C++14 standard (n4140).  Drafts can be found on [github](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/tree/master/papers). *—End Note*

> **D.5 C standard library headers  [depr.c.headers]**
>
> \$^1\$ For compatibility with the C standard library and the C Unicode TR, the C++ standard library provides the 26 C *headers*, as shown in Table 155.
>
> \$^2\$ Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding `cname` header is placed within the global namespace scope. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope (§3.3.6) of the namespace `std` and are then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit *using-declarations* (§7.3.3).
>
> \$^3\$ [ *Example:* The header `<cstdlib>` assuredly provides its declarations and definitions within the namespace `std`. It may also provide these names within the global namespace. The header `<stdlib.h>` assuredly provides the same declarations and definitions within the global namespace, much as in the C Standard. It may also provide these names within the namespace `std`. *—end example* ]

---

```
using namespace std;
```

`using` directives can be useful when used correctly (namespace composition).  Importing all symbols into the global namespace to avoid namespace qualification is not one of them.  Associated side effects include [collisions and ADL-related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1453605/3762339).

---

```
const string Score[] = {"0", "15", "30", "40", "ADV"};
```

Use enumerations to represent sets of related constants allowing you to separate logic from I/O (not all tennis scoring system use 0-15-30-40, some simply use 1-2-3-4).

Avoid global variables.  `Score` is only depended on by a single entity (`Game`).  Make `Score` a data member of `Game`.

---

```
Game::Game() {
    scores[0] = 0;
    scores[1] = 0;
}
```

A default constructor should do more than just initialize members variables with constants.  Prefer to use in-class data member initializers and use the compiler-generated default constructor.

```
class Game {
    std::string players[2]{};
    int scores[2]{};
  public:
    // Use compiler-generated default constructor
    Game() = default;
    // ...
};
```

---

```
bool Game::createPlayer(int playerId, string playerName) {
    if (playerId == 0 || playerId == 1) {
        players[playerId] = playerName;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Prefer to acquire resources and establish all invariants on construction (see [RAII aka SBRM, CADRe](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)).  With multi-stage initialization, every method needs to address the problem "what do you do when the object is in the uninitialized state?".  To handle this, you provide more conditionals which make your functions heavier.

Your program doesn't handle the uninitialized `players[]`.  Reading from the array is undefined behavior.

Prefer `std::size_t` instead of `int` or `unsigned int` for indices.  From the C++ Standard:

> **18.2 Types [support.types]**
>
> \$^6\$ The type `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

---

```
string Game::getName(int playerId) {
    if (playerId == 0 || playerId == 1)
        return players[playerId];
    else
        return "N/A";
}
```

Avoid `else` after early exits (`return`, `break`, `continue`, `throw`). You will reduce indentation level and amount of code that needs to be tracked when reading.

```
string Game::getName(int playerId) {
    if (playerId == 0 || playerId == 1) {
        return players[playerId];
    }
    return "N/A";
}
```

`"N/A"` could be the name entered by the user which is the same type/value as the error value.  Notify the callee when errors occur through an exception mechanism.  There are plenty of options that exist in the modern C++ world.  Options include plain exceptions (`<stdexcept>`), error conditions (`<system_error>`), and `union` types (`boost::optional`, `std::optional`, [Alexandrescu's `Expected<T>`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Andrei-Alexandrescu-Systematic-Error-Handling-in-C)).

```
    std::string Game::getName(int playerId) {
        range_check(playerId);
        return players[playerId];
    }
    // ...
private:
    void range_check(const std::size_t index) {
        if (index >= std::size(players)) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Invalid Index");
        }
    }
```

---

```
bool Game::setScore(int playerId, int score) {
    if (score < 5)
        scores[playerId]=score;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Avoid [magic constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants). Use `constexpr` named variables or enumerations to give the literals meaningful context.  Some literals are acceptable (`-1`, `0`, `1`, `nullptr`, `'\n'`).

Make sure you are compiling with warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra`).  If you plan to write standard conforming code, enable pedantic warnings as well (`-pedantic`).  GCC and Clang both report:

> ```
> In member function 'bool Game::setScore(int, int)':
> warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
> ```

From the C++ Standard:

> **6.6.3 The `return` statement [stmt.return]**
>
> \$^2\$ ... Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a `return` with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

---

```
int Game::getIntScore(int playerId) {
    return scores[playerId];
}
```

Your other functions performed a range check.  What about `getIntScore` and `getStringScore`?

---

```
srand(time(NULL));
// ...
int pointWinner = rand()%2;
```

[`rand()` is considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).  Prefer to use [C++ standard `<random>` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random), [`boost::random`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), or the [PCG Random library](http://www.pcg-random.org/).

---

```
bool stop = false;
while(!stop) {
   // ...
    if (myGame.hasADV(pointWinner)) {
        stop = true;
        cout << //...
    } // ...
}
```

Rather than having a variable to track the state, consider interrupting the control flow with a `break`.

```
while (true) {
    // ...
    if (myGame.hasADV(pointWinner)) {
        std::cout << //...
        break;
    } // ...
}
```

Keep functions short and simple, to the point that they perform a single logical operation.

---

```
else if (myGame.getIntScore(pointWinner)>myGame.getIntScore(pointLooser) && myGame.getIntScore(pointWinner)>=2)
```

Test! Test! Test! Your score keeper exits early.  A sample output:

```
The winner of the point is John
Score : John 15 - 0 Paul
The winner of the point is John
Score : John 30 - 0 Paul
The winner of the point is John
Winner is John
```

John should hit match point (40) before winning.